# UINavigationBar setTitleTextAttributes with UnderLine Text

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, fonts

I am trying to `setTextAttribute` with UnderLine in all Views using this code

```
 [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor],
//        NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle),
        (NSString *) kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName:@(kCTUnderlineStyleDouble),
        NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:17]}];
```

but its not working , I know another approach using creating custom `UILabel` with `NSAttributedString` and setting it on TitleView but is there any other way to achieve this using appearance protocol?

Answer (score 7):

NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName should do that job for you.

Try this Dude:

```
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{
                                 NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @1,
                                 NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor],
                                 NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:17]
                                 };

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:attributes];
```

**Updates:**

I refered the Apple's documentation, **It seems to be not possible through appearance protocol.**

It says

"You can specify the **font, text color, text shadow color, and text shadow offset** for the title in the text attributes dictionary, using the text attribute keys described in NSString UIKit Additions Reference."

I tried by creating the new simple project as well. Couldn't see the line.

[image]
[image]

**Apple Documentations:**

[UINavigationBar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/titleTextAttributes)

[NSString Keys for Text Attributes Dictionaries](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Keys_for_Text_Attributes_Dictionaries)

Comment: i have tried Dude but not working on Title with Redcolor display on navbar

Comment: where u have put this code. in App delegate didfinishlaunching method?

Comment: yes on AppDelegate do we need to do any special settings in Storyboard also or in Plist in order to affect this ?

Comment: create a new sample project, then put navigation bar there, test with this code. it may help u to find out the problem is in this code or somewhere u r changing the attribute!

Comment: Hm... The underline's not working for me in this code or any code I've tried... Does it show up for you @Vijay-Apple-Dev.blogspot.com?

Comment: @vijay its not working for me also in any other code i am using iOS 8 SDK iPhone 6 simulator